# Not able to specify data rate on radiotap_header in pcap_sendpacket

Tags: c, pcap, radiotap

I'm trying to send raw frames over WiFi using pcap_sendpacket. I'm thus using a standard radiotap_header for this and I specify a data rate (I tried 2 Mbs, 5 Mbs). However, it seems that the WiFi interface does not take this rate into consideration and always send at 1 Mb/s. I can see this on wireshark. Is there a way to send frames at a higher rate ?

Comment: This might either be a driver issue or a network adapter issue.  On what version of what OS are you doing this, what type of Wi-Fi adapter do you have, and what driver does it have (on Linux, for example, there might be multiple different drivers available for the adapter)?

Comment: I'm on linux (ubuntu 14.04 low latency kernel) and I'm using libpcap to send frames. The wifi adapter is a TP-Link with an Atheros chipset. I have to check for the WiFi driver. So it might be related to the driver ?

Comment: Yes, it might be related to the driver - it might not support injecting frames with a specified data rate.

Comment: Hi Harris, I'm using ubuntu standard Atheros driver, is there another that I can try ?

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you got any answers for your question!